Microsoft Graph API - MSTeams application permissions required to create group chat with app installed
We have a Microsoft Teams application that coordinates users in different ways. We'e moving away from Teams channels and instead want to invite users into a group chat and perform some actions there.
The issue we're facing is that in order to manage the chats we create we are having to request a high level permission at the azure / app level that is worrying admins of those Teams installs.
Namely: TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteAndConsentForChat.All
We also request Chat.create - but no one is worried about that!

We have defined our application with the appropriate RSC permissions to write messages, add users, etc. These are all defined in the manifest for the application etc and all good - none of them are unreasonable and all are tied to the resource we are creating via the .Chat.
However it seems that in order to request and gain those permissions we seem to have to install / add our app into the chat we just created. I guess this makes sense as we need to request permissions on a particular resource - what doesn't make sense to me is that in order to install our app we seem to need TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteAndConsentForChat.All.
This permissions is quite pervasive which obviously is a slightly scary for someone to agree to (despite the fact you can only install yourself into a chat you know the ID for - and we do not request any permissions to list chats).
Am I missing something obvious? There does not seem to be anything in the API to create a chat and request RSC permissions on it at the same time. Nor does there seem to be a way to create a chat and include your bot / app in the members.
Equally seems bizarre that as an application I can create and manage a chat - but have no permissions on it at all to perform actions?
It feels like we're missing something obvious here about how to manage these resources correctly - would love to hear from someone who's done something similar!

We are checking this with engineering team, we will update you soon.

Could you please share your tenant and app ID? We will give them access so that you can try it out as a private preview.
